# Which Sci-Fi work first showed Tardigrades?

Tags: history-of

Tardigrades are tough creatures which can survive extreme heat, cold, pressure, radiation etc and that's why they are appearing in Sci-Fi works these days. Here are few examples:

- *Star Trek: Discovery* (2017) made Tardigrades famous.
- In *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (2018), Hank Pym encountered Tardigrades in the Quantum realm. And, in the mid-credit scene, Hank Pym or his wife warned Scott Lang about Tardigrades ("Stay away from Tardigrade Fields. They look cute, but they will eat you.").
- [When the Tardigrades came...](http://flscifi.blogspot.com/2015/12/short-story-when-tardigrades-came.html?m=1) (2015) is the first instance I can find.

Which Sci-Fi work first showed Tardigrades?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tardigrade) gives a lower bound of 1773 (before that, the species had not yet been described) and an upper bound of 2014 (see the "in popular culture" section - apparently someone made a sci-fi video game about them).

Comment: The sci-fi video game maker is suing Star Trek Discovery, actually, for tardigrade story line and character likeness: http://trekzone.org/1701/201808232505

Comment: @DarthLocke Haha.. Seriously? I doubt that they have secured copyright of tardigrade. This is definitely publicity stunt, nothing else.

Comment: @NewtScamander  I'm not saying they will be successful, because I think there are a lot of other pop cultural influences in Discovery too (Hannibal, Fringe, Game of Thrones, Biblical Allegory) and you're probably right about the copyright, but I can't deny that the character looks/roles are rather similar...

Answer (score 6):

[The Search For WondLa has Tardigrades in it](http://wondla.wikia.com/wiki/Otto).  It was published in 2010.

Answer (score 5):

I read a short story called "The Tardigrotifer" in a compilation. It seems to be this one: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1367547. I read it in the 80's, and that site says 1978 publication date.

It's about a tardigrade crossed with a rotifer, and from what I remember it had the tardigrade's body and the rotifer's feeding tentacles. It was also gigantic, about the size of a hippo, so might not be exactly what you are looking for.